# How to adapt Python loop generation to be conditional?

Tags: python, string, loops, tuples, conditional-statements

I have some Python code like this:

```
print seq(y), '\t', ', '.join(['%s-%s'%i for i in holetbl[y]])
```

But I would like to make the inner string generation conditional.  The `i` in the loop is a tuple of two values which get put into the two `%s` values in the string.  In the case that the tuple values are the same, I would instead only like one value as in:

```
print seq(y), '\t', ', '.join(['%s'%i for i, j in holetbl[y]])
```

How can I make a condition to test if `i == j` and if so to only print the `i` value, otherwise, both the `i` and `j` values as in the original above?

Comment: Do you control the creation of the `holetbl` tuples?  If so, you may have options to clean the data more easily or efficiently during generation than doing it after the fact at output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

```
print seq(y), '\t', ', '.join('%s' % i if i == j else '%s-%s' % (i, j)
                              for i in holetbl[y])
```

**Note**

You don't need to formulate a list to pass to `str.join`. A simple generator expression would work. This will be more memory friendly and comparably faster

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the 'simple generator expression' with an example?

Comment: @WilliamKF: The posted example uses generator rather than LC.

Comment: I'm missing how what you posted is different (other than the addition of the conditional expression) than what I originally had so as to make it more efficient by using a simple generator expression.

Comment: @WilliamKF: Adding Brackets `[]` around the expression makes it a List Comprehension, ex `['%s' % i if i == j else '%s-%s' % (i, j)
                              for i in holetbl[y]]`, this will force Python to generate the List before feeding to `str.join`.

Comment: That is pretty subtle, I missed that difference in comparing the two!

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
'%s-%s'%(i,j) if i != j else '%s'%i
```